What Flow operator am I looking for
Suppose I have getPeople(): List<Person> and getStudent(ssn: String): Student
data class Person(val name: String, val ssn: String)
data class Student(val ssn: String, val grade: Char)
data class ReportCard(val name: String, val grade: Char)

I want a List<ReportCard> but I don't want to wait for getStudent to form a report card.  For example, getPeople() returns [("Joy", "111"), ("Tom", "123"), ("Jerry", "567")].  Suppose that grades earned were:
Joy: C
Jerry: F
Tom: A
I'm going to join a Person with a Student by ssn to form a ReportCard in a scrollable list, so I want fields in ReportCard to be filled in asynchronously.  If an error occurs, I ignore it and resume.
Emitting whenever a grade is returned:
[("Joy", ''), ("Tom", ''), ("Jerry", '')] <--getPeople() done
[("Joy", 'A'), ("Tom", ''), ("Jerry", '')] <--getStudent(Joy) done
[("Joy", 'A'), ("Tom", ''), ("Jerry", 'F')] <--getStudent(Jerry) done
[("Joy", 'A'), ("Tom", ''), ("Jerry", 'F')] <--getStudent(Tom) error
Another solution is emitting after the grades are finished:
[("Joy", ''), ("Tom", ''), ("Jerry", '')] <--getPeople() done
[("Joy", 'A'), ("Tom", ''), ("Jerry", 'F')] <--getStudent() calls done

You say you want a list of report cards, but do you want a new list emitted every time any one person’s grade arrives? Or do you only want to emit two lists, one without grades, and then one with grades after they have all arrived?

I want a list of report cards without waiting for the grade part from getStudent.  So I don't want to emit a list any time a person's grade arrives because that implies waiting on the network request from getStudent.  kind of like the behavior of flow combine but one request is dependent on another (student is dependent on person).

I understand we want to initially emit a list without grades without waiting. What I’m asking is, there will be many getStudent requests, so do you want to wait for all of them to finish before you emit the second list, or do you want to emit many lists, emitting every time you receive a grade for each student?

ok, I added more context in my question and an example illustrating your points.
May I ask you to show an example of both, it would be useful to compare the two and learn from.

I don't think there's simple set of flow operators you can use for this, so we need to build something with the flow builder to get the functionality.
Also, there's no such thing as an empty Char like you seem to have in your example solutions, so I will use nullable Char and null to represent no grade available.
Supposing these are your available inputs:
val people: Flow<List<Person>> = //...

suspend fun getGradeForSsn(ssn: String): Char? { //...

First, for simplicity within the flow, create the error catching version of this function:
suspend fun getGradeForSsnOrNull(ssn: String): Char? =
    try { 
        getGradeForSsn(ssn) 
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        throw(e)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }

I haven't tested these solutions, but maybe they can be a start for you to build something that works.
Then for your second case where you only emit two report card lists for each input people list, you could do:
val reportCards = people.flatMapLatest { peopleList ->
        flow {
            emit(peopleList.map { ReportCard(it.name, null) })
            val finalList = coroutineContext {
                peopleList.map { 
                    async { ReportCard(it.name, getGradeForSsnOrNull(it.ssn)) }
                }.awaitAll()
            }
            emit(finalList)
        }
    }

The first case is more complicated. Maybe something like this:
val reportCards = people.flatMapLatest { peopleList ->
        flow {
            val reportCardsBySsn = peopleList.associate { 
                it.ssn to ReportCard(it.name, null)
            }
            emit(reportCardsBySsn.values.toList())
            coroutineContext {
                peopleList.forEach { 
                    val grade = getGradeForSsnOrNull(it.ssn)
                    if (grade != null) {
                        reportCardsBySsn[ssn] = reportCardsBySsn[ssn].copy(grade = grade)
                        emit(reportCardsBySsn.values.toList())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


ok I appreciate it.  I did something similar by building a custom flow.  I fetched the people and emit a Placeholder report card with name.  For each person I call getStudent(ssn).  I update the report card corresponding to the student with the grade and emit my new list.
